# Restore to a point in time

Tags: sql-server

I copied over the mdf and ldf for a database (Sql 2005 Express) to my machine and in my Sql 2005 (Developer Edition) attached them. I had set the logging in the source machine to full since I need to research an issue.

Now, in my SQL Server I have 2 database, DAProd that I just attached and DARestore that I just created. I want to restore DARestore with a point in time version of DAProd. When I bring up the Restore dialog, it does not show DAProd in the source dropdown. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. You need the various point in time backups of DAProd, not a current copy of DB reattached.

Comment: I'm a newbie at this. So on the machine that is running DA Prod, when I set this up, I set recovery to full. One month later I created a full backup and moved it to my dev machine. I'm assuming this will have the db and log backup necessary for me to recover to a point in time?

In SQL Server Management Console, when I open a new query, which db so I select to run your statements in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have the backup of DAProd (both full and log). You don't need to attach a copy of DAProd, the backup process can create the 'copy' database for you. But is OK if you did attach it, won't matter.

First you run a restore of your most recent full backup of DAProd that is older than the moment in time you want to stop the recovery:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DAProd] FROM DISK = '<yourfullbackup>' WITH NORECOVERY;
```

Next you start to recover the LOG backup that occurred after the full backup but are still prior to the moment in time, one by one:

```
RESTORE LOG [DAprod] FROM DISK = 'yournextlog' WITH NORECOVERY;
```

Now you restore the log that contains the moment in time you want to stop:

```
RESTORE LOG [DAProd] FROM DISK = 'yournextlog' WITH STOPAT = '<timetostop';
```

The final step is to take the DAProd database online. BTW this will rollback any uncommitted transaction 'in flight' at your moment in time:

ALTER DATABASE [DAProd] SET ONLINE;

You can now look at the database as it was in the moment in time you wish, as *if it would roll back any pending transaction at that moment*.

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a point in time restore, you need the various point in time backups of DAProd, not a current copy of DB reattached.

Please See [How to: Restore to a Point in Time (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx)

Also: [Point in Time Recovery](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3530616/Point-in-Time-Recovery.htm)

[How to: Restore a Database Backup (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)